# Repository pattern and localized lookup tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am trying to grabs the idea of the pattern repository and trying to get it implemented in database structures I've already set up in the past. I'm now trying to get the best practice to work with my lookup tables. I've created a test project to play around and this is my database model:

[image]

You can see that I have three tables for the lookups: Lookup, Language and LookupLanguage. Language table simply contains the languages.

[image]

Lookup tables holds the different types used throughout the models.
[image]

And LookupLanguage links the both tables together:
[image]

I've created anew project with all the models 1 to 1 to the database tables:
[image]

I also created a generic repository and a generic CrudService interface:

```
public interface ICrudService<T> where T : IsActiveEntity, new()
{
    int Create(T item);
    void Save();
    void Delete(int id);
    T Get(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func, bool showDeleted = false);
    void Restore(int id);
}
```

Now, according to the following post: [When implementing the repository pattern should lookup value / tables get their own Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168430/when-implementing-the-repository-pattern-should-lookup-value-tables-get-their) , the repository should hide the underlying database layer. So I think I need a new implementation of a service and/or repository to get the lookups, but then, where do I have to tell in which language I need to have the lookup?

Let's take the status (new, accepted, refused) from the company as an example.

The company model is as follow:

```
public partial class Company : IsActiveEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public System.Guid StatusGuid { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusGuid")]
    public virtual Lookup Status { get; set; }
}
```

I guess I don't need to have a separate implementation of a repository?
But I need a separate implementation CompanyService.

```
interface ICompanyService : ICrudService<Company>
{
    IQueryable<LookupLanguage> GetStatuses(Guid languageguid);
    LookupLanguage GetStatus(Guid statusguid, Guid languageguid);
}
```

Is this the correct approach, or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Creating a Generic LookupRepository in your case in a better option** because of your table schema and maintainence perspective.

I'm not sure whether you are using both Service Locator and Repository pattern or just Repository because of the name `ICompanyService`. But regardless, I agree that Repositories should not represent tables 1-1 always but they do most of the times.

The SO link you provided has a different table structure than yours. You have a generic lookup table vs the link has a separate table for each lookup. In the case where you have separate tables it makes sense to have the lookup repository method go with the entity repository since you will have a separate code to fetch the data for each lookup(as they have separate tables with different schema).

But in you case you have a single table that stores all the lookup types for each language and it makes sense to have a single LookupRepository that returns all the various types of lookups based on Language and LookupType. If you create each lookup method in separate entity repositories (like GetStatuses in CompanyRepository and GetStatuses in ContactRepository) you will have to repeat the logic in the method for each repository.

Think if you change the schema of the lookup table (say add a column) and you want to test all places the lookups are used it will be nightmare if you have lookup methods all over the place and pretty easy if you have one method in LookupRepository.

```
interface ILookupService : ICrudService<Lookup>
{
    IQueryable<Lookup> GetStatuses(Guid languageguid, LookupType lookupType);
    Lookup GetStatus(Guid statusguid, Guid languageguid, LookupType lookupType);
}
```

Comment: I think I'm going to use this approach as you mentioned. I can even use a more generic method (a mere Get with specifying the type as a parameter). I suppose that the translated status will be a concern of the viewmodel of the presentation layer as @flup mentioned?

Comment: Yes create a generic method. That's what I meant but the method name I chose wasn't correct. I don't quite understand your question about translated status.

Comment: When showing the status of the company on the screen, it must say "Accepted" for example in the language of the user. My viewmodel does have another implementation of the company's properties where .Status will contain the string "Accepted". It's only at this point (loading the data in the viewmodel) and the awareness of the user's language in the presentation layer that this has to be done?

Comment: It depends but yes that's one of the options.

Answer (score 2):

As regards your question, "Is this the correct approach" - this entirely depends on your specific needs.

What you have done doesn't seem to have any real issues. You have implemented the repository pattern using generics which is great. You are using interfaces for your repositories which allows for easier unit testing, also great!

One of your tags seems to indicate you are interested in the `Entity Framework`. You do not seem to be using that. The `Entity Framework` would simplify your code by creating the boiler plate classes for you. You can still use your repository pattern code with the classes created by the `Entity Framework`.

It seems that you are confusing the idea of a service and a repository. A repository is a general object which allows you to get data from a store without caring about the implementation. In your example, `ICompanyService` is a repository.

Comment: It seems so that I'm mixing the concepts op services and repository. I will make changes in my test application. My specific needs is to implement this in a large scaled project with web and Windows applications, mobile apps,...

Answer (score 1):

It is really controversial topic and there are different approaches to this problem. In our data  logic we are not using repository pattern because we **do not want to** abstract most of the benefits of Entity Framework. Instead, we pass the context to the business logic which is already a combination of UoW / Repository pattern. Your approach is okay if you are going this way on all of your company services. **However** what I have seen so far, putting methods to the related services by their return values is the best approach to remind where they are. For instance if you want to get the company lookup, create a `ILookupService` and put `GetLookUpsByCompany(int companyId)` method to retrieve the company lookups.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue with the linked response. Repositories ARE linked to database entities, considering the Entity Framework itself as a uow/repository implementation is a best example. On the other hand, services are for domain concerns and if there is a mismatch between your database entities and domain entities (you have two separate layers), services can help to glue the two.

In your specific case, you have repositories although you call them services. And you need a repository per database entity, that's just easier to implement and maintain. And also it helps to answer your question: yes, you need the extra repository for the linking table.

A small suggestion. You seem to have a generic query function that only accepts where clauses

```
IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func, bool showDeleted = false);
```

If you already follow this route that allows arbitrary filtering expressions (which itself is a little arguable as someone will point out that you can' possibly guarantee that **all technically possible** filters can be executed by the database engine), why don't you allow all possible queries, including ordering, paging, etc:

```
IQueryable<T> Query { get; }
```

This is as easy to implement as your version (you just expose the dbset) but allows clients to perform more complicated queries, with the same possible concern that such contract is possibly too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Localization is a presentation layer thing. The lower layers of your application should bother with it as little as possible.

I see two different kind of lookups: translations of coded concepts (Mr/Miss/Mrs) and translations of entity properties (company name maybe, or job titles or product names).

**Coded concepts**

I would not use lookup tables for coded concepts. There is no need to bother the lower layers at all with this. You will only need to translate them once for the entire application and create simple resource files that contain the translations.

But if you do wish to keep the translations in the database, a separate lookup repository for the codes or even per code system will sort of replace the resource file and serve you fine.

**Entity properties**

I can imagine different/nastier localization issues when certain entities have one or more properties that get translated in different languages. Then, the translation becomes part of the entity. I'd want the repository to cough up entity objects that contain all translations of the description, in a dictionary or so. Cause the business layer should not worry about language when querying, caching and updating relations. It should not ask the company repository for the Dutch version of company X. It should simply ask for company X and be served a Company object that contains its name in Dutch, English and French.

---

I've one more remark about the actual database implementation:
I think the lookup tables are distracting from the actual entities, to the point where you have forgotten to create a relation between person and person company. ;) I'd suggest putting all translations of entity properties in a single XML type column instead.

This illustrates why the repository should handle entities plus translations. If you were to make this storage layer level implementation change at some point, i.e. go from lookup tables to xml columns, the repository interfaces should remain the same.